# Como cambiar codigo escrito en java a javascript

Tags: javascript, java

Hola no conozco mucho js y tengo que pasar este codigo de java al lenguaje, si alguien me explica cual seria el semejante del codigo en js, o como puedo transcribirlo ya que no entiendo muy bien como transcribir interface a js y cual es su funcionamiento en js.

````
interface IAve {  
    void comer();
}
interface IAveVoladora {  
    void volar();
}

interface IAveNadadora {  
    void nadar();
}

class Loro implements IAve, IAveVoladora{

    @Override
    public void volar() {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void comer() {
        //...
    }
}

class Pinguino implements IAve, IAveNadadora{

    @Override
    public void nadar() {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void comer() {
        //...
    }
}```
````

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript no es un lenguaje tipado, por lo que interface no existe, de igual forma si no me equivoco (que alguien me corrija) una clase no puede extender de dos objetos, lo mas cercano a tu código seria

```
class Loro extends IAve{
    volar() {
        //...
    }

    comer() {
        //...
    }
}
```

El tipado lo puedes mantener si en lugar de `javascript` lo pasas a `typescript`